# angular databinding 2 numbers to equal another

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have 2 divs that must always equal 100%. So they each start out 50%. The one on the left, can be changed from 1-99 (as an input), and the other must match that so they both always stay 100%.

for example: div A = 35%, div B must auto-change to 65%. I know how to two databind values, but not so that they each equal another value combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just keep subtracting div a from b
first div

```
<div>{{A}}</div>
```

second div

```
<div>{{100-A}}</div>
```